# How to create a chat screen in Android?

Tags: android, chat, smack

I'm creating an Android chat application. I want chat screen to include features like a new UI screen for chat thread with a different user. But I don't know to move further with it. Should I use service or asyntask or is there any other way. Please help me get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. if you use each thread for each user, you will spawn many threads (memory, and time to create and clear...).

You should use a service to listen when receive message (this is an easy work by using intent), and you can do in your main UI Thread.

Comment: Thanks:) I did the same way. I stored all the messages in the database. Whenever i click on a particular user in userlist, i would send that userid to the chatscreen activity and based on the userid it would load corresponding messages from database.

Answer (score 0):

The chat gets closed (The network connection with the server/another device which the user was chatting with) once the activity closes, so I don't see a reason to use a serivce/AsyncTask. Just have a thread waiting for data from the socket streams, and show that data to the user once it arrives.

Comment: Sorry for giving partial information. I'm using Smack API to create my chat cient. So, the chat doesn't get closed until the activity is stopped by the Android OS. Also, the user may be chatting with say A. B sends him a message which comes as a notification. When user clicks on notification a new activity will be started which shows all chat messages with B. How to go with it if there are 10 users or like that. GTalk uses gestures to switch between chat threads. But i'm not understanding how they map UI Activities with Chat Threads.

Comment: I am not familiar with Smack API. But if you want the network connection to stay alive even when the activities are dead, use a Service.

Comment: Looks like there is a SO tag for the Smack API. I'll add it to your question.